# Vue JS way to toggle classes for Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have tried a couple ways to do this, but it does not seem to work. Returns activeClass is not defined. And classList with plain JS also returns undefined in Vue. Can not seem to nail this down in the docs provided.

Here is what I got as a boiler plate.

```
let attributes = {
    activeClass: 'tab--active'
}

    Vue.component('insurance-menu', {
        template: `
            <ul id="tabs">
                <li><a class="tab" v-bind:class="{activeClass}" href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="tab" v-bind:class="{activeClass}" href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="tab" v-bind:class="{activeClass}" href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a class="tab" v-bind:class="{activeClass}" href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>`,
        data: function() {
            return attributes

        },
        methods: {

        }
    });

    let tabs = new Vue({
        el: '#menu-container'
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array instead of Object to return your value:

```
<a class="tab" v-bind:class="[activeClass]">
```

You can make you code more clean like this:

```
<a :class="['tab', activeClass]">
```

Comment: It is saying active class not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local data to add a certain class on your views, something like this:

`<div v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }"></div>`

On your js:

`data: {
  isActive: true,
  hasError: false
}`

> **FYI** you can use
>    just :class (without the v-bind) and it will be perfect aswell.

That code will add the 'active' class to the div if the `isActive` property returns `true`

> Source: Docs and personal usage ( https://vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax )